# How do I output an ArrayList in a Window?

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, window

I try to display an `ArrayList` in a nice way into an `InfoBox`.
The `ArrayList` contains names (String) of files that got edited in a certain period of work and gets created automatically.

If I use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`, I get a super long window that is impossible to read.
It would be better to have a nice list view.
How do I do that?

The parts of the code affected:

//List initiation

`List output = new ArrayList();`

//FIll List with data

```
for (String fileOrFilderName : changedFilesAndFolders) { 
    output.add(fileOrFilderName);
}
```

//Output

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "Edited or added files",
                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Output:
[Too long window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onpa5.png)

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: //List initiation
`List output = new ArrayList();`
//FIll List with data
`for (String fileOrFilderName : changedFilesAndFolders) {
      output.add(fileOrFilderName);`}
//Output
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output, "Edited or added files", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);`

Comment: Create your own dialog, insert a JList, make it scrollable and insert your values.

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundle your `output` into a `javax.swing.JList` decorated by a `javax.swing.JScrollPane`.

For example:

```
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

    //FIll List with data
    for (String fileOrFilderName : changedFilesAndFolders) {
        output.add(fileOrFilderName);
    }

    //Output

    JList<String> list = new JList<>(new Vector<>(output));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(list), "Edited or added files", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for, it worked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Benjamin Maier, you can add any JComponent om the JOptionPane. So what you do is to add JScrollpane to it containing JList.